# Rails precompile error - too hard to find which file is causing the error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, asset-pipeline

I did the `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean; RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace`

And I got

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"
  (in /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/Dropbox/Rails/dqa_dev_server/vendor/themes/lenord-single-page-theme/application.css)
(sass):7322
```

However in `lenord-single-page-theme/application.css`

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

I commented out all the  `config.assets.precompile`

```
  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  #config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.css )
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( vendor/themes/* )
  #config.assets.precompile += %w( vendor/themes/**/application.js )
  #config.assets.precompile += %w( vendor/themes/**/application.css )
  # config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif] 

  # Precompile *all* assets, except those that start with underscore
  #config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/
```

How can I get more information regarding the error?

Comment: There is syantax error somewhere in your scss file.

Comment: Yes, when there are dozens of files, this error is not helpful.  Maybe something that can take a folder and css-check every file in it?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the syntax error somewhere in the SASS code, why not to use a SASS debugger?

There are several of them on web. For example two for Chrome (can be integrated with the TextMate): [Sass Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sass-inspector/lkofmbmllpgfbnonmnenkiakimpgoamn) and [Sass Sleuth](http://www.mobify.com/blog/sass-sleuth-debugging-sass-in-webkit-browsers/).

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error before and it drove me insane because I couldn't find the syntax error.

But then I `renamed all my .css files to be .scss` and all the errors disappeared.